# How to get the final element of a hierarchical array in scala and apply aggregate functions on it?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, explode

I have a hierarchical array in a dataframe as :

```
customerId  accounts
IND0002 [["IND0002","ACC0155","323"],["IND0002","ACC0262","60"]]
IND0003 [["IND0003","ACC0235","631"],["IND0003","ACC0486","400"],["IND0003","ACC0540","53"]]
IND0004 [["IND0004","ACC0116","965"]]
```

I need to extract the last element lowest element from each list in the array
Ex : from the 1st row I should get `323,60` and 2nd row should get `631,400,53`

I tried using explode function, but its extracting just the first elemnts

```
customerId  accounts    col
IND0002 [["IND0002","ACC0155","323"],["IND0002","ACC0262","60"]]    ["IND0002","ACC0155","323"]
IND0002 [["IND0002","ACC0155","323"],["IND0002","ACC0262","60"]]    ["IND0002","ACC0262","60"]
IND0003 [["IND0003","ACC0235","631"],["IND0003","ACC0486","400"],["IND0003","ACC0540","53"]]    ["IND0003","ACC0235","631"]
IND0003 [["IND0003","ACC0235","631"],["IND0003","ACC0486","400"],["IND0003","ACC0540","53"]]    ["IND0003","ACC0486","400"]
IND0003 [["IND0003","ACC0235","631"],["IND0003","ACC0486","400"],["IND0003","ACC0540","53"]]    ["IND0003","ACC0540","53"]
IND0004 [["IND0004","ACC0116","965"]]   ["IND0004","ACC0116","965"]

val newDF1 = CustomerAccountOutput.withColumn("accounts", $"accounts"(size($"accounts")).minus(1))

CustomerAccountOutput.select($"customerID",explode($"accounts"))
```

Comment: seems just use `.map` and some array operations is ok. Is there any concern on this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform) function with a lambda function where for each sub-array you get the last element by using [`element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#element_at) with index `-1`:

```scala
val newDF1 = CustomerAccountOutput.withColumn(
  "new_col", 
  expr("transform(accounts, x -> element_at(x, -1))")
)

newDF1.show(false)

//+----------+--------------------+--------------+
//|customerId|            accounts|       new_col|
//+----------+--------------------+--------------+
//|   IND0002|[[IND0002, ACC015...|     [323, 60]|
//|   IND0003|[[IND0003, ACC023...|[631, 400, 53]|
//|   IND0004|[[IND0004, ACC011...|         [965]|
//+----------+--------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

got satisfactory result by using slice and withcolumn
[image]